Why is my Ts.ED application not returning the correct response in production but works fine in development?
I'm using Ts.ED for building a backend REST API, and everything works fine in my development environment, but when I deploy to production, the server doesn't return the expected responses. I am getting error can't parse JSON.  Raw result:
InternalServerError in production environment.
Here are the details:

In development, I'm running the app locally (tsed built-in development server), and everything works as expected.

Some things I've tried:

Verified that the environment variables are set correctly in production (NODE_ENV, database URLs, API keys).
Checked that the acceptMimes setting is configured to accept application/json in production.
Set up the CORS configuration to allow cross-origin requests from my frontend.
The Content-Type header for requests in production seems to be correctly set to application/json.
expected response should be in json format
{
"name": "HTTP_EXCEPTION",
"message": {
"name": "HTTP_EXCEPTION",
"type": "HTTP_EXCEPTION",
"status": 404
},
"status": 404,
"errors": [],
"stack": "stack details "
}

In my service
 try{
        if (someArray.length === 0) {
            throw new Error(`Mapping not found for id: ${id} and version: ${version}`);
         }
     } catch (error) {
            throw error;
     }

in my controller
    @Returns(200, response)
    @Get('/getdata/info')
    public async Info(
        @Required() @QueryParams('id') id: string,
            @Required() @QueryParams('version')version: number,
    ): Promise<response>  {
        return this.serviceName.serviceMethod({ Id, version });
    }


What is the actual respone you are getting from the server? Please [edit] your post and add the text.
